# How to drop observations in data frame in R? max.print?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am so sorry about that I have to ask such a dumb question on here but I'm having trouble filtering a variable as I try to clean up my data set. I am working with a dataset with 8,000 survey responses and want to filter out all of the responses that are given by females.

Because 1 is male and 2 is female, I am trying to drop all rows in which sex=2.

```
library(dplyr)
(setwd("~/Desktop"))

df <- read.csv(file="Parenting.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

filter(df, sex==1)
```

When I do this, I get the below response and the number of observations in my data frame does not change and my "sex" variable retains the "2" values

```
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4544 rows ]
```

While trying to research a solution, I also tried to include:

```
options(max.print=999999)
```

before my filter statement but that also left my number of observations and my variable observations unchanged.

Thank you for any help. I am desperate!

Comment: assign the value back to a new object. `df1 <- filter(df, sex==1)` and then check `df1`.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why exactly are you using `filter()`, which according to its documentation is used to apply *linear filtering to a univariate time series or to each series separately of a multivariate time series*? To me this looks like a job for `subset()`.

Comment: @Where'smytowel You're missing `dplyr` from the tidyverse

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question accordingly and added the dplyr tag

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah! That worked. Can't believe it was that easy of a fix

Answer (score 2):

@ronak-shah is correct. The reason, you face this issue is because your command really prints the output to console. You need to assign it to a variable.

```
df <- read.csv(file="Parenting.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

df1 <- filter(df, sex==1)

head(df1)

unique(df1$sex)
```